# All Nodes in a linked list point to same object

Tags: c, linked-list

The problem is somewhere in here....

```
char buffer[80];
char *name;
while (1) {
    fgets(buffer, 80, inf); //reads in at most 80 char from a line
        if (feof(inf)) //this checks to see if the special EOF was read
            break;     //if so, break out of while and continue with your main
        name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
        ....
        name = strtok(buffer, " ");//get first token up to space
        stock = newStock(name,...)
        ....
    }
```

I'm working in C with generic linked lists. I made a list implementation that I've tested and know works with chars. I'm trying to add stocks (I created a stock struct) to the linked list, with each node of the linked list holding a stock struct, but when I finish reading in the stocks all of the nodes point to the same struct and I can't figure out why. Here's some snippets of my code

```
list *list = malloc(sizeof(list));
newList(list, sizeof(stock_t));

while(1) {
    ...
    (read from file)
    ...
    stock_t *stock;
    stock = newStock(name, closes, opens, numshares, getPriceF, getTotalDollarAmountF,getPercentChangeF,toStringF);
    addToBack(list, stock);
}
```

Here's the newStock function:

```
stock_t *newStock(char *name, float closingSharePrice, float openingSharePrice, int numberOfShares, getPrice getP, getTotalDollarAmount getTotal, getPercentChange getPercent, toString toStr) {

    stock_t *stock = malloc(sizeof(stock));
    stock->stockSymbol = name;
    stock->closingSharePrice = closingSharePrice;
    stock->openingSharePrice = openingSharePrice;
    stock->numberOfShares = numberOfShares;
    stock->getP = getP;
    stock->getTotal = getTotal;
    stock->getPercent = getPercent;
    stock->toStr = toStr;
    return stock;
}
```

In a way I see what's wrong. newStock returns a new pointer every time, but it always gets stored in the variable 'stock' which is what every node points to, so it's going to be equal to whatever the last pointer newStock returned was...but I don't see the way around this. I tried having newStock return just a stock_t, and doing addToBack(list, &stock), but that didn't solve the problem either.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is some code from the list:

```
typedef struct node {
    void *data;
    struct node *next;
}node_t;

typedef struct {
    int length;
    int elementSize;
    node_t *head;
    node_t *tail;
} list;


void newList(list *list, int elementSize) {
    assert(elementSize > 0);
    list->length = 0;
    list->elementSize = elementSize;
   list->head = list->tail = NULL;
}

void addToBack(list *list, void *element) {

    node_t *node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    node->data = malloc(list->elementSize);
    node->next = NULL; //back node

    memcpy(node->data, element, list->elementSize);

    if (list->length == 0) { //if first node added
        list->head = list->tail = node;
    }
    else {
        list->tail->next = node;
        list->tail = node;
    }

    list->length++;
}
```

Here's code from the stock struct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef float (*getPrice)(void *S);
typedef float (*getTotalDollarAmount)(void *S);
typedef float (*getPercentChange)(void *S);
typedef char *(*toString)(void *S);

typedef struct stock{
    char *stockSymbol;
    float closingSharePrice;
    float openingSharePrice;
    int numberOfShares;
    getPrice getP;
    getTotalDollarAmount getTotal;
    getPercentChange getPercent;
    toString toStr;
   }stock_t;
```

The generic functions probably seem like overkill but this is for homework (if you couldn't tell already) so we were asked to specifically use them. I don't think that has anything to do with the problem though.

Here are the definitions for those functions anyway

```
float getPriceF(void *S) {
    stock_t *stock = (stock_t*)S;
    return stock->closingSharePrice;
}

float getTotalDollarAmountF(void *S) {
    stock_t *stock = (stock_t*)S;
    return ((stock->closingSharePrice) * (stock->numberOfShares));
}

float getPercentChangeF(void *S) {
    stock_t *stock = (stock_t*)S;
    return ((stock->closingSharePrice - stock->openingSharePrice)/(stock->openingSharePrice));
}

char *toStringF(void *S) {
    stock_t* stock = (stock_t*)S;
    char *name = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    //sprintf(name, "Symbol is: %s. ", (stock->stockSymbol));
    return stock->stockSymbol;
}

void printStock(void *S) {
    char *str = toStringF(S);
    printf("%s \n", str);
}
```

And this is how I'm traversing the list:

```
typedef void (*iterate)(void *); //this is in the list.h file, just putting it here to avoid confusion


void traverse(list *list, iterate iterator) {
    assert(iterator != NULL);

    node_t *current = list->head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        iterator(current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

And then in my main I just called

```
traverse(list, printStock);
```

Comment: The problem is in your list code, not what you are showing here.

Comment: Okay, let me edit the original post and put some of that code in. I'm confused though because I tested the list on ints and arrays of chars and it worked fine.

Comment: `stock_t *stock = malloc(sizeof(stock));` -->> `stock_t *stock = malloc(sizeof *stock);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any problems with your code (that would cause your problem, anyway - there are places where you don't check the return from `malloc()` and stuff like that, but those are not relevant to this question). You don't supply the definition of `stock_t`, so I made a new data struct, and a new couple of functions, otherwise I just copied and pasted the code you provided:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

/*  Your code starts here */

typedef struct node {
    void *data;
    struct node *next;
}node_t;

typedef struct {
    int length;
    int elementSize;
    node_t *head;
    node_t *tail;
} list;


void newList(list *list, int elementSize) {
    assert(elementSize > 0);
    list->length = 0;
    list->elementSize = elementSize;
    list->head = list->tail = NULL;
}

void addToBack(list *list, void *element) {

    node_t *node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    node->data = malloc(list->elementSize);
    node->next = NULL; //back node

    memcpy(node->data, element, list->elementSize);

    if (list->length == 0) { //if first node added
        list->head = list->tail = node;
    }
    else {
        list->tail->next = node;
        list->tail = node;
    }

    list->length++;
}

/* Your code ends here */

/*  I made a new struct, rather than stock, since you didn't supply it  */

struct mydata {
    int num1;
    int num2;
};

/*  I use this instead of newStock(), but it works the same way  */

struct mydata * newNode(const int a, const int b) {
    struct mydata * newdata = malloc(sizeof *newdata);
    if ( newdata == NULL ) {
        fputs("Error allocating memory", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    newdata->num1 = a;
    newdata->num2 = b;
    return newdata;
}

/*  I added this function to check the list is good  */

void printList(list * list) {
    struct node * node = list->head;
    int n = 1;
    while ( node ) {
        struct mydata * data = node->data;
        printf("%d: %d %d\n", n++, data->num1, data->num2);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

/*  Main function  */

int main(void) {
    list *list = malloc(sizeof(list));
    newList(list, sizeof(struct mydata));

    struct mydata * data;

    data = newNode(1, 2);
    addToBack(list, data);
    data = newNode(3, 4);
    addToBack(list, data);
    data = newNode(5, 6);
    addToBack(list, data);

    printList(list);

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs this:

```
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src$ ./list
1: 1 2
2: 3 4
3: 5 6
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src$
```

demonstrating that you have a 3 node list, with all nodes different and where you'd expect them to be.

Either there is some other problem in code you're not showing, or for some reason you are thinking each node points to the same `struct` when it actually doesn't.

One possibility is that you have a `char *` data member in your stock struct. It's impossible to tell from the code you provided, but it's possible that you really are creating different nodes, but they all end up pointing to the same `name`, so they just look like they're the same. If you're assigning a pointer to `name`, you should make sure it's freshly allocated memory each time, and that you're not just, for instance, `strcpy()`ing into the same memory and assigning the same address to each stock `struct`.

EDIT: Looks like that was your problem. This:

```
name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
....
name = strtok(buffer, " ");
```

should be:

```
name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
....
strcpy(name, strtok(buffer, " "));
```

Right now, you `malloc()` new memory and store a reference to it in `name`, but then you lose that reference and your memory when you overwrite it with the address returned from `strtok()`. Instead, you need to *copy* that token into your newly allocated memory, as shown.

Comment: Thank you for all the effort. I tried my code too with ints and arrays of chars and it worked which is why I'm so lost. I'm pretty sure it is pointing to the same struct. I traverse the list by following the next field until it's null and printing out node->data->stockSymbol. I've gone into debugger and checked to make sure I wasn't just iterating wrong and they are all the same. i.e. if I print out node->data->stockSymbol and node->next->data->stockSymbol, they are the same. I'll share the stock struct code and maybe it will reveal something. I'll edit it into the original post

Comment: @user3344699: Check the last paragraph of my answer I just added, maybe that's what's going on if it's the stock symbol you're using to check all this. If they're all pointing to the same stock symbol, it'd explain how they *look* the same, but actually are separate nodes in the way that they are when you've tried with `int` and friends. You could try printing out the stock price or similar, I'd wager a pound they'll all be as different as you'd expect. Also, just to be on the safe side, check you're not just reading the same line over and over again from the file.

Comment: Ah! You were correct, the numbers for price are correct. It's just the name that's all the same. I guess I should have checked more thoroughly. I will look over my code now and see if I can figure out the problem with my char*.

Comment: @user3344699: Almost certainly you're using a single `char` buffer to read in the symbols from the file, and just assigning the address of that buffer to each node. As a result, the buffer ends up containing the last symbol you read from the file, and all the nodes point to it. You'll need to `malloc()` new memory each time and copy the buffer into it (or use `strdup()` and do it in one go) and assign the address of *that* new memory to your new node.

Comment: I'm still not seeing it, I'll put what I'm doing in the OP. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Try changing `name = strtok(buffer, " ");` to `strcpy(name, strtok(buffer, " "));` Right now you `malloc()` that memory for `name`, but you lose your reference and throw it away again when you assign the return from `strtok()` to it. Instead, you need to copy the string *into* that new memory you allocated. If that doesn't work, post your entire code and your data file into your question.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks a ton for all the help.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted.